# SHA-1 Signing key

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2

How does 1 get an ios signing key for an ionic app. I know that ios native apps get it generated automatically by XCode, but I have built my app with ionic cordova. I managed to get my android signing key with the terminal command

> $ keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.meteor/android_bundle/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

but I don't know if I can get an ios signing key by replacing androiddebugkey with iosdebugkey or something. I have to get a APIkey from google to use for my google maps plugin and I need the sha1 key for ios. I couldn't find out how to get it for ios anywhere in the web other than using xcode.

I am using ionic 2 with cordova and xcode does not run ionic 2 apps. does anyone know how I can get it?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are talking about, but on your last point, I can open my ionic2/3 projects in Xcode and use the run feature in Xcode to run the Ionic app on my iPhone.

Comment: Actually xCode runs very well with Ionic 2 apps. For build/run on an actual device, a Apple computer is required.